# Gem Koala undefined methods 'get_object'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, koala

I wanted to use [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) Gem to connect to Facebook api but I faced some problems.

Before I used Koala, I used [omniauth-facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) to implement the SSO of my app.

And then I added `gem koala` in Gemfile and run bundle install.

In my `user.rb'

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.name = auth.info.name
    user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
    user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
    user.save!
  end
end
def facebook
  @facebook = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
end
```

And then I go to consoele.

```
u = User.first
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 1, provider: "facebook", uid: "100003544640331", name: "Gary Lai", oauth_token: "AAAB9iQ1zm2oBAA1w3DFBZBC2V73uheQCs43dHpOu1LYsYixqvu...", oauth_expires_at: "2012-10-02 09:55:39", created_at: "2012-07-27 16:41:18", updated_at: "2012-08-03 09:55:42">
```

It works.

However, when I follow the kaola tutorial, I got this error message.

```
u.facebook.get_object("me")
NoMethodError: undefined method `get_object' for #<Koala::Facebook::API:0x007fb07ab1e108>from (irb):8
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Why I got this error message ?

Comment: Finally, I solved this problem.
Cause my koala version were 1.0. Therefore I have to use `gem 'koala', :git => 'https://github.com/arsduo/koala.git'`

Comment: Ok, please specify answer by yourself, and check it. And why do you not used release koala (1.6.0)?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this problem. Cause my koala version were 1.0. Therefore I have to use `gem 'koala', :git => 'https://github.com/arsduo/koala.git'`